# Are Doom Bots attacking everything?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've played a few games on the new doom bots mode and found out that they automatically destroys wards, but not gp barrels, making him extremely OP.
Does it work with other non-player entities?

- Shaco's boxes?
- Zyra's plants?
- Do they step on Rek'Sai's tunnels?
- Tibbers/Daisy/Yorick's Mist Walkers or Maiden of the Mist?
- Mordekaiser's ult-killed champions / dragons?
- Bard's Caretaker's Shrine (W)?
- Elise's spiders?
- Skarner's passive points

Also, can Kindred have an enemy jungle camp marked?, or a camp that is getting aggo on your lane?
Answers only showing one of these behaviors are also appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doombots while strong still use the AI that exists for the base version of the game. Bots are pretty dumb with mechanics beyond last hitting, skirmishing, and rotations. The strength of doombots just comes from the crazy abilities that they have. So if regular bots don't react to it the doombots won't. Skarners shrines are a definte example of this. Bots have no idea how to play vs that mechanic. A good rule of thumb is if it requires the bot to move to it to destroy (skarner, reksai, bard) bot's wont care. Elise's spiders will never be targeted over elise so the only time they'd die is if aoe is being aimed at Elise but not to kill her spiderlings. Player entities that attack bots when the champ is out of range (boxes, tibbers, ect) will get focused but at an extremely low level of priority compared to champs and minions.

While your kindred question is technically not related to the doombots, yes kindred can mark any enemy jungle camp that has its large monster alive (in fact the passive only works on neutral monsters and enemy camps). If a camp is currently aggro'd it will not be marked.